# Building an employee directory in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I've spent the better part of a day trying to build an Employee Directory in SP Online. I am able to pull a list of users using the Search Results Web Part and the query text `contentclass=spspeople`

It's working quite well except it includes external users, who are not employees. I have searched high and low for a property I can use to exclude external users and come up empty handed.

Ideally I'd only like to show users with an Office 365 license (this will eliminate staff members who have left). Has anyone done something similar before?

Any help appreciated!

Tas

Comment: You might have to go for a custom (Javascript) DisplayTemplate and extract the info from the ctx object

Comment: A good reference to get started, http://sympmarc.com/series/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365/. As Danny said though, you'll have to fiddle with your display template to filter out what you don't want.

Comment: Thank you both. I can see how those approaches will work, however I am still stuck on how to filter the data. Is there a way of accessing all managed properties for given user or users?